# Mounted /lib on logical volume - Can't run anything now

Tags: ubuntu, mount, lvm, disk-usage, libraries

I'm working on a server which works with logical volumes. The root partition was full, basically because of a large `/lib` directory. I wanted to set this `/lib` to a logical partition, as I did already with `/usr`, `/var`, `/home` and `/opt`.

So I created the volume by

```
sudo lvcreate -L 20G -n lib vg00
```

and the filesystem by

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/vg00-lib
```

then I mounted it by

```
mount /dev/mapper/vg00-lib /lib/
```

Now I can't run any command anymore. The mount command somehow failed.

```
df -h bash: /bin/df: No such file or directory
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are a lot of essential libraries in /lib, so umount the empty filesystem (reboot is the easiest way for you), and copy all files before next remount.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Is there another way of unmounting it besides rebooting? A couple of applications are still running, I don't know if that's a case after a reboot.

Comment: `/bin/busybox umount /lib` if busybox-static is installed

Comment: That saved me! I now can rescue my backup files and will then reboot the system. I still don't understand what went wrong though. Probably /lib isn't supposed to be mounted after all?

Answer (score 0):

If a mount of /lib makes essential libraries like cp, cd, mount, umount unavailable, a

/bin/busybox umount /lib

unmounts the directory. The libraries will work again.

Thanks https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/182562/ipor-sircer !

Comment: just to mention: it only works if `busybox-static` is installed, the basic `busybox` also depends on /lib.

Comment: Of course. I did this on a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Minimal Server installation.

Answer (score 0):

*/lib* contains libraries that are linked to by other applications. When you ran `mount /dev/mapper/vg00-lib /lib/` you mounted a fresh filesystem with nothing on it, in place of */lib* which effectively made all those libraries unavailable. While they remained on disk, they became inaccessible.

So what you need to do is mount your new logical volume to a different directory, such as */mnt*: `mount /dev/mapper/vg00-lib /mnt`

Then you'll be able to copy */lib* to */mnt* (which will become your new */lib*)

## Side note

You...

> ...wanted to set this /lib to a logical partition...

However, a logical volume and a logical partition are not the same thing. Partitions exist at a lower level (BIOS, GPT, etc) while a logical volume is part of LVM. It was probably just a typo, but I wanted to make that clear.